# Is it normal to detect voltage inside a disassembled laptop?

Tags: laptop

[In this video I used a non-contact voltage detector and placed it in various points on the surface of the disassembled laptop chassis, behind the keyboard and touchpad. Overall there is not much voltage detection but there is one point in the middle with particularly strong voltage. It is strange because as you can see there is nothing there!](https://streamable.com/vgljs)

**Question:** is it normal that there is voltage inside the disassembled laptop?

The base in the video is resting on a wooden desk.

The frame around the laptop is made of aluminum and the base is carbon-fiber.

I have removed the power, battery, and motherboard CMOS battery.

Everything has been disassembled down to the base, what is remaining is the keyboard and monitor and touch pad.

(extra info:
This laptop fails to switch on and I was trying to figure out what could be wrong.)

Comment: Questions on this site must be fully stated within the content of the post itself.  You cannot rely on a video link for the basics, you must use the "edit" button to add an explanation in words of the situation you are asking about, particularly what you measured and where.  A video may only supplement.

Comment: without even looking at the video, it's probably a capacitor somewhere keeping a charge.

Comment: What are you using to detect something, flashing and beeping?

Comment: It looks like one of those non-contact AC detector pens that electricians use to detect live wires.  video could be a fake... or there could be an electric field on the user and the laptop is acting as an antenna.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Something, somewhere is holding a charge which is giving you the voltage reading. It's almost certainly a capacitor - if you want to discharge them you can short circuit them individually with a wire.